# Jquery functions not working on dynamically loaded contents(not binding function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, eventhandler

I have a question in javascript, that I have a form which has add and delete button, on clicking them, some of the form fields gets repeated and deleted as per button click, 
In those fields I have also datetimepicker, and I want that it should work in generated fields also, but its not working, although I have used class instead of Id for giving them functions like

```
    $(function () {
    var now = new Date();
    $('.time_in').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: now,
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
});
```

But it is working only in the first field instead of all the fields, I have also attached some event handlers after changing the values of datetimepicker, but I don't have issues with them, I know that how to do it.

I just wanted to ask that how to give function or initialize fields with datetimepicker..

Below is the Screenshot

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtmQ.png)

Comment: put your code on fiddle and share the url

Comment: Show the code for `add` and `delete` functionality

Comment: `$('.time_in')` is not "live" like CSS. It only contains the elements already existed when it is called.

Comment: I have put the code on fiddle but I don't know why its not working... Its first time I have put the code on fiddle Here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/388vtbhr/

Comment: @qtuan Yes that's what I am also worried about, what is the way, to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi since you are creating textboxes dynamically you should use event delegation, use jQuery's `on()` method (requires jQuery version  1.7x+).

**Add**

```
 $('body').on('focus',".time_in'", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
```

here is a small demo http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/1013/

Comment: Yes Its working, but is there any way to prefill the textboxes like the first one ?

Comment: @Manish i have updated the fiddle to preload the textbox with dates... kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/SJ7bJ/1015/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the code to add the datetimepicker on each field after you've added the new elements.  Consider refactoring the code to assign the dateptimepicker into a separate function that can be called from the init and from the #add function.

```
$(function () {
    add_time_in_datetimepicker();
});

function add_time_in_datetimepicker() {
    var now = new Date();
    $('.time_in').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: now,
        format: 'HH:mm'
    });
});
```

And then at the end of the #add function, make the same call.  You'll need to do this for all of the datetimepicker classes that you want to add dynamically.